# Datadog export logs more than 5,000

Tags: datadog

I want to export more than 5000 logs in csv from datadog, is there any configuration I need to do in datadog so that I can download 10k,20k logs at a time.

I also checked on [official web page logs explorer](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/) but it doesn't helped out.

Answer (score 5):

This is the top search result for getting past the 5,000 record limit at datadog, but the current answer above doesn't work anymore. For anyone else who comes across this, I had success using this: https://github.com/wegift/datadog-downloader

Only exports to JSON but that's easy enough to parse to CSV after.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this tool: https://github.com/DataDog/csv_exporter

If you don't have python installed you can start it in a docker container.

Comment: Yes, I knew through datadogs api we can download required logs, but I want configuration in datadog itself so that my client can download it.